# Magento 2 : How to Change Category Page on Button Click

Tags: magento2, category, custom

I have a many categories in my magento 2 website. I want to make a custom button and when I am click on this button it will redirect me on next category. Can any one help me how to achieve this functionality. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you need?

Comment: you can do this by using custom code of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieve this using below code 
In your html code add below

```
   <div class="next-prev-cat">
        <span class="prev-cat">PREVIOUS CATEGORY</span>
        <span class="next-cat">NEXT CATEGORY</span>
   </div>
```

and then use below jQuery Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  require([
    'jquery'
    ], function($){
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var nextuUrl = jQuery(".category-list").find(".active").parent(".category-list").next(".category-list").find("a").attr("href");
        var prevUrl = jQuery(".category-list").find(".active").parent(".category-list").prev(".category-list").find("a").attr("href");    
        //alert(nextuUrl);
        if(typeof nextuUrl == 'undefined'){
          $(".next-prev-cat").find(".next-cat").css("display","none");
        }
        if(typeof prevUrl == 'undefined'){
          $(".next-prev-cat").find(".prev-cat").css("display","none");
        }
        jQuery(".next-cat").on('click', function(){
          location.href = nextuUrl;
        });
         jQuery(".prev-cat").on('click', function(){
          location.href = prevUrl;
        });

      });
    });
</script>
```